# Can't get the data object with .data(el,'dataname').sublev

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I'm storing data with this code.

```
baslat: function(data) {
            var $bu = $(this).get(0);
            if(!$.data($bu, "ipucu_secenekleri")){
                metodlar.domEkle.apply(this, data);
                var ipucu_secenekleri = $.extend({}, s, data);

                $.data($bu, 'ipucu_secenekleri', ipucu_secenekleri);

            }

            return this;
        },
```

But when I try to get the data named ipucu_secenekleri

```
            domEkle: function (data) {

               var $bu = $(this).get(0),
               icerik = $.data($bu,"ipucu_secenekleri");
               console.log(icerik) //undefined
            }
```

Thats more... These are undefined too:

```
$.data($bu).ipucu_secenekleri

var datam = $.data($bu);
datam.ipucu_secenekleri;
```

But here is the funny part. When I try to get the whole data and console it I can see the data that I stored...

```
$.data($bu); //it returns the data object which contains ipucu_secenekleri.
```

But as you can see asigning to a variable is useless. I cannot reach the sub levels nor for in loop can.

```
for(var i in datam){console.log(datam[i])} //no effect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is a low-level method. You should try the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method :

In your code replace

```
$.data($bu, "ipucu_secenekleri")
```

with

```
$bu.data("ipucu_secenekleri")
```

...and so on.